# How to print a list without it showing brackets and "" in the output ? Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, list, printing, python-3.x

So say I have a list named `myList` and it looks something like this :

```
myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

How would you print it to the screen so it prints :

```
abc
```

(yes, no space inbetween)

If I use `print(myList)`
It prints the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And now you have three upvotes :)

Comment: It's always hard to read other people's minds, but I'm guessing they downvoted you because your question doesn't show any attempt to solve the problem yourself. I think that's unfair, because this isn't exactly an easy thing to search for. (Everything that seems like a good search turns up `repr`-vs.`-str` differences and other things that are just going to confuse you.) But some people are unfair and quick to downvote. In the future it might help to explain how you tried to search, and they'll be more sympathetic. Or you could just ignore them; it's not like the downvotes really hurt you…

Comment: This is basically identical to one of your previous questions.

Comment: I guess that is what earned the -1s?

Answer (score 9):

With Python 3, you can pass a separator to [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). [`*` in front of `myList`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) causes `myList` to be unpacked into items:

```
>>> print(*myList, sep='')
abc
```

Comment: I don't know if it works, but +1 for making me go read the Python 3 spec :)

Comment: @icedwater, added a wee bit of explanation!

Comment: Wow, I can +1 the "same" answer twice if it's edited! Nice, but... seems like a bug to me. Then again, not all edits are this small...

Answer (score 8):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
''.join(myList)
```

Example:

```
>>> myList = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> print(''.join(myList))
abc
```

This *joins* every item listed separated by the string given.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like the OP wanted Python 3, so I added parens around your `print` and changed the docs link to 3.x. Otherwise, perfect answer.

Comment: @abarnert Yep, thanks a lot. Title says 3.3.2

Comment: Funny how we both missed that. If it's not in the tag, we either assume 2.x, or try to figure it out heuristically from the text, without even looking at the giant bold letters. :)

Comment: @abarnert Heh, I'm a 2.7 user, so I always assume 2.x :D (kinda bad that I do that, but meh :3)